# Postgresql static column value in updatable view

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have merged two tables *foo* into *bar* together.

*foo* would have the rows:

- id
- name

and *bar* would have:

- id
- name
- type

Every entry of *foo* I inserted into bar recieved the value **2** in the type column.

Now I want to create an updatable view for *foo*, which queries *bar* to return the inserted entries.
If I insert something into teh view, the type column of *bar* should always be **2**.

I tried something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_foo AS
  SELECT bar.id, bar.name, 2 AS type
    FROM bar
   WHERE bar.type = 2;
```

But this still sets type to null on an insert.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify an `ON INSERT` rule for the view lie this:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE RULE v_foo_insert_rule AS ON INSERT
    TO v_foo
    DO INSTEAD INSERT INTO bar(id, name, type) VALUES (NEW.id, NEW.name, 2);
```